# Cannot start zookeeper server. No jdk directory

Tags: java, unix, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to start kafka on UNIX, but first I need to run zookpeer. 
I have kafka 2.12 version from https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.0.0/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz
I run command `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`, but I got an error:

```
/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 306: /project/multiar/jdk1.7.0_17_x64/bin/java: No such file or directory
/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 306: exec: /project/multiar/jdk1.7.0_17_x64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory.
```

I have Java 8 jdk in path:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)
```

Why I cannot run zookeper server? Should I install jdk 7 or change something in `.sh` files?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: /project/multiar/jdk1.7.0_17_x64

Comment: In your `~/.bash_profile`, simply add `export JAVA_HOME=/change_to_java_8_dir/java_home -v 1.8` so that Java 1.8 is set to your shell environment. You will then need to restart your session in the terminal (or reload your bash profile).

Comment: It did not help

Comment: do you have permission on jdk directory?

Comment: I created some bash file, where I export JAVA_HOME path and then want to run zookeeper. Path is set to 8, but error still exists.

Comment: have you set it somewhere in zkEnv.sh ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to solve the same problem. It happened to me after an Ubuntu update (not sure completely)

[image]

This is how I resolved the problem

1  Check the Java version

[image]

2 Check for all Java versions installed

[image]

3 Add JAVA_HOME to environment variables

[image]

[image]

4 Check the JAVA_HOME

[image]

After I set the JAVA_HOME correctly zookeeper starts correctly (complete logs are not shown here)

[image]

Comment: Note: Releases before Kafka 2.0 won't work with Java 9 or 10

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I did same thing - exported JAVA_HOME in my application directory and it works now.

Comment: Adding the `JAVA_HOME=pathtojava` in `/etc/environment` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

exported JAVA_HOME in my application directory and it works now.

**export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/**